# How to find my servlet for web.xml?

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml

I am using `wildfly`, `JBOSS`
And I made a `Servlet`...called `ServletImg`

My folder structure looks like this:

WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/ServletImg.java

Now i am trying to add him into the `web.xml` file...like this:

```
  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>ServletImg</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>ServletImg</servlet-class> <!-- Here is the problem -->
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>ServletImg</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/ServletImg</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Error msg:

> `servlet.class` must be valid fully qualified class name

Any suggestions on resolving the issue?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm

Comment: Add  name of your Servlet class,including the package structure.For ex : com.mypackage.MyServlet

Comment: believe it or not, but my code is from that site...but i am not using Tomcat

Comment: thx guys, it worked

Comment: read about web.xml, how to configure all these.http://www.javatpoint.com/welcome-file-list

Answer (score 2):

The point is, everything you need to know is in the question:
Use a fully qualified name.

To solve your problem, all you need to do is:

- Create a package to put your servlet in,
- Use the name `my.package.ServletImg` in the `web.xml`.

It isn't a good practice to put Java classes in the default package, and can be confusing sometimes to servers, as you just faced it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very clearly given in the error that you've mentioned.

You need to mention the Servlet class name with the full package structure.
For example, check this!

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>examples.Hello</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Observe that the tag `< servlet-class>` is a fully qualified Class name, that includes the package in which the class has been declared.

Answer (score 0):

Create .java classes in src folder not in WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/

and next if you are creating java dynamic web project then select Dynamic Web module version 2.5 so that you can find web.xml file in Path   /ProjectName/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml